# Replace django.core.mail.send_mail() across all apps?

Tags: django, django-mailer

Is it possible to replace calls to `django.core.mail.send_mail()` across my entire project (including third-party projects in my INSTALLED_APPS) with a custom `send_mail()`?

I'm integrating django-mailer with my project, which provides a replacement `send_mail()` for  `django.core.mail.send_mail()`. Since both use the same function signature the docs suggest importing the django-mailer version in places where you'd normally import the Django-provided version like so:

```
# favour django-mailer but fall back to django.core.mail
from django.conf import settings

if "mailer" in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    from mailer import send_mail
else:
    from django.core.mail import send_mail
```

This works for my own app code, but I'd also like to make the same changes across third-party apps that use `django.core.mail.send_mail()`. Right now, I hit errors when these apps try to send e-mail.

Does Django provide any kind of hook to replace `django.core.mail.send_mail()`, or is there a workaround? Right now I'm looking at forking each third-party project that sends e-mails and adding the conditional import code above, but that is obviously not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django has [email backends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/email/#email-backends) that let you override the way that emails from `django.core.mail` are sent, instead of going through SMTP. There are some that let you save them locally and so on; `django-mailer` also includes one ([as described in usage.txt](https://github.com/pinax/django-mailer/blob/master/docs/usage.txt#L72)) to do exactly what you want to do.